# powershell exit code implentation

Tags: exit

Hi I am not a script expert and im looking for help:
I would like to have a exit code, im not sure how this works do...

(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA

if value  = 0 the exit code should be 
Write-Host "Success Message" Exit 0

if the value is 1 the exit code should be
Write-Host "Error Message" Exit 1001

but i have no clue how to implent this, could someone please help me, once i see the script working i can have an idea how this exactly works.

This cause were having MAX Remote,

here is some info:
https://dashboard.systemmonitor.co.uk/dashboard/helpcontents/index.html?script_guide.htm

if we can implent this correctly the dashboard would see the correct exit code.

Thank You

$enablelua = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
if ($enablelua -eq $0){
Write-Host "UAC Is Enabled"
Exit 0
}
else {
Write-Host "UAC Is Disabled"
Exit 1001
}

doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$enablelua = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
if ($enablelua -eq 0){
Write-Host "UAC Is Disabled"
Exit 1010
}
else {
Write-Host "UAC Is Enabled"
Exit 0
}
```

this works ;) just sharing